# How to setup Not Exactly C or nxt-python on Arch Linux for lego mindstorms in 2023?

Tags: usb, python, arch-linux

I have an old NXT Lego-Mindstorms Robot. I did some major digging, but I havn't been able to connect to the Robot via USB with my arch linux system.
When I type `nxt-test`, I get the following error message:

```
Find brick...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/johannes/.local/bin/nxt_test", line 21, in <module>
    with nxt.locator.find_with_options(options) as b:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/johannes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nxt/locator.py", line 289, in find_with_options
    return find(find_all=find_all, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/johannes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nxt/locator.py", line 215, in find
    raise BrickNotFoundError("no brick found")
nxt.locator.BrickNotFoundError: no brick found
```

Well so the brick could not be found. When I type `lsusb` with the cable plugged in and without the cable plugged in, I get the same output. That's not what I should be seeing, is it? On the brick however, a usb-connection is established.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to troubleshoot this.
Any advice on how I could achive that is appreciated!